# function as event parameter in a on() method

Tags: jquery

is it possible for the on() method to bind function in this way? I want a function to be the event of on method.

```
function clickfunction (){

}


$('#some').on('clickfunction',function({
    alert('something');
)};
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: why don't u give it a try??

Comment: `$('#some').on('click', clickfunction);`????

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: He is trying to make so that everytime the function `clickfunction` gets called, he can call his callbacks.

Comment: @iJay I tried the code above, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to [trigger a custom event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) inside your function, like so:

```
function clickfunction (){
    $('#some').trigger('clickfunction');
}
```

Then you can bind whatever listener you wish.

Here is a <kbd>[**working demo**](http://jsbin.com/ikoZeku/1/edit)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is

```
$("#some").on("click", clickfunction);
```

Then, whenever someone clicks on the DOM element with id='some', clickfunction will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what specific event you want to run the function on. In other words, you have to tell what jQuery should listen for from a user. So, as referenced by @msquiteri and @Arun P Johny, you can do:

`$('#some').on('click', clickfunction);`

If you are asking if you can call `clickfunction` in such a way that jQuery will know that you are calling the function when a user `clicks`, as far as I know this functionality doesn't exist. You must explicitly define the event.